# Collabnet Apache Server and Rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, collabnet

I'm using Collabnet Subversion Server with Apache.  I'm trying to perform a simple rewrite directive under a specific directory and I can't seem to find out what the issues are.  I have another server running Apache alone and the rewrite directives work as expected.

My .htaccess (simplified just to get the thing working)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* http://%{SERVER_NAME} [R,L]
```

Using the above .htaccess file contents, my page won't even load...  If I remove

```
RewriteEngine On
```

the page will load, but the rewrite will not occur.
My http.conf (or the relevant parts):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteLog "rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9

<Directory "wwww">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

The RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel directives also seem to be ignored.  After restarting the Collabnet/Apache service, the rewrite.log file is created, but nothing is ever written to it.

I guess my real question is, has anyone else here configured Collabnet Apache service successfully with rewrite directives?  As I mentioned above, I have another server running Apache alone and I can successfully perform the rewrites.

**Or, does someone know why my logs aren't working properly?**  If perhaps I can get that far, maybe I would be able to debug the issue on my own...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot help with the .htaccess part of this, but just wanted to say that CollabNet is just distributing binaries they have built.  It is still a normal Apache httpd server build from the official source release.  The Subversion Apache modules would not in any way interfere with the ability to use mod_rewrite and these other features.  So you should be able to just focus on getting the Apache configuration correct.  The fact that the binaries came from CollabNet should not be relevant.

I am sure it is just a typo above, but I notice you probably have an extra "w" in the "wwww" Directory directive.

Comment: It seems that the configuration between the two different apache services are nearly identical.  And yes, the extra "w" is a typo.